# Obj-C - Add activity indicator to pull down to refresh?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've added a 'pull down to refresh' function to my TableView inside a ViewController. The data refresh works perfectly, but I'm wondering how I can add the classic activity indicator into the top when the refresh is executed?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
 [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 //[self.mytable addSubview:refreshControl];
 UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
 tableViewController.tableView = self.tableView;
 tableViewController.refreshControl = _refreshControl;

}


-(void)refreshData
{

   UITableViewController *tableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
   tableViewController.tableView = self.tableView;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
   [tableViewController.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    
  
}
```

Comment: guys find swift version of refresh control here
https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-pull-to-refresh-to-a-table-view-or-collection-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working!

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIRefreshControl *refreshControl;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];
     
            self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
            self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"Pull To Refresh"];
            [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            [self.tableView addSubview:self.refreshControl];
            
        }
    
    -(void)refreshData
    {
        
      
        // Wait 1 sec before ending refreshing for testing
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue is that both `viewDidLoad` and `refreshData` are creating new `tableViewControllers` but they should be updating your existing one.

If your class in `ViewController.m` is a subclass of `UITableViewController` you can update your code to use the current view controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    [_refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshData) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.refreshControl = _refreshControl;
}


-(void)refreshData
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing]; 
}
```

Another issue is that `refreshData` immediately calls `endRefreshing` so the refresh Controller wont have any time to be visible before it ends. Normally you'd have an asynchronous task running, like a network request, then call `endRefreshing` once that completes. To fake it you can delay calling `endRefreshing` with the following.

```
-(void)refreshData
{
    // Wait 1 sec before ending refreshing for testing
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
    });
}
```

Comment: guys find swift version of refresh control here
https://cocoacasts.com/how-to-add-pull-to-refresh-to-a-table-view-or-collection-view

Comment: The activity indicator still doesn't appear for me when refreshing begins?